# Do parent controls have an effect on the TAB INDEX of the inner control?

Tags: c#, winforms, tab-ordering

In my form I have a `splitter` and then a `panel` inside it and then an `ActiveX` control from VB 6.0 (It is something like a tree control) inside this `panel`.

I have set a `TabIndex` for this `ActiveX` control and set the `TabStop` to `true` and also set the `Tabstop` of its parents like `panel`,`splitter`,etc to `false`.

But when I press `TAB` key focus does not move to this control... why is that?! what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

By disabling `TabStop` on the parent controls you also skip all children, so just don't do it and it should fix your issue. (Didn't test, but should work that way.)

Comment: well some of them like the splitter one did have tabstop of true, but the borders of the splitter were getting the focus and selected!

Comment: Think you can't avoid that. But how about adding code to the `Enter` event (maybe `GotFocus`) that sets the focus to your ActiveX control?

Comment: yes, I started doing it by code..so now should I somehow turn off the TabIndex so they wont interfere?

Comment: I guess the topmost parent will still require it to be set (just not the children and sub children) so you actually receive focus using the tab key.

Comment: this is wrong,   If you disable tab stop on a parent control , YOU DO NOT skip the children!  How would that be of any use to anyone?! give the parent the next tab number, but tab stop to false, then start the children from 1 again and set them to tabstop = true

Comment: So, what does it do? Just keeping the parent from receiving focus (e.g. groups)? Keep in mind we're talking about an ActiveX control, not your standard Winforms control. As said above I'm not sure (never tried it). So just to be sure, you should post that as your own answer.

Comment: @StevenMartin This comment made my day :) Thanks!